# System.ArgumentException: 'Should specify SharedAccessKeyName'

Tags: c#, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-dps

I'm getting this error from Azure IoT Provisioning Service when creating the provisioning client.

```
System.ArgumentException: 'Should specify SharedAccessKeyName'
```

I copied the Connection String from the Portal, what could be wrong?

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Provisioning.Service;

namespace EnrollmentApp
{
    class Program
    {
        private static string ProvisioningConnectionString = "HostName=happybeerhub-us.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=test-device-01;SharedAccessKey=tawpddfqUt3EHZg9a5tUzQ5fjros7zMhKsZbmuXzwXE=";
        private static string EnrollmentGroupId = "test";
        private static string X509RootCertPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location), @"key.pfx");        

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RunSample().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            Console.WriteLine("\nHit <Enter> to exit ...");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static async Task RunSample()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting sample...");

            using (ProvisioningServiceClient provisioningServiceClient =
                    ProvisioningServiceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(ProvisioningConnectionString))
            {
                #region Create a new enrollmentGroup config
                Console.WriteLine("\nCreating a new enrollmentGroup...");
                var certificate = new X509Certificate2(X509RootCertPath);
                Attestation attestation = X509Attestation.CreateFromRootCertificates(certificate);
                EnrollmentGroup enrollmentGroup =
                        new EnrollmentGroup(
                                EnrollmentGroupId,
                                attestation)
                        {
                            ProvisioningStatus = ProvisioningStatus.Enabled
                        };
                Console.WriteLine(enrollmentGroup);
                #endregion

                #region Create the enrollmentGroup
                Console.WriteLine("\nAdding new enrollmentGroup...");
                EnrollmentGroup enrollmentGroupResult =
                    await provisioningServiceClient.CreateOrUpdateEnrollmentGroupAsync(enrollmentGroup).ConfigureAwait(false);
                Console.WriteLine("\nEnrollmentGroup created with success.");
                Console.WriteLine(enrollmentGroupResult);
                #endregion

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you are missing the `SharedAccessKeyName` so the validation tries to check it and as it is null in your case you get the exception.

As you can see in the [ServiceConnectionStringBuilder.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/blob/master/provisioning/service/src/Auth/ServiceConnectionStringBuilder.cs) the correct connection string format is

```
/// A valid connection string shall be in the following format:
/// <code>
/// HostName=[ServiceName];SharedAccessKeyName=[keyName];SharedAccessKey=[Key]
/// </code>
```

Also in line 128 you can see the check which throws your exception:

```
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SharedAccessKeyName))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Should specify SharedAccessKeyName");
        }
```

Now you might think that ServiceConnectionStringBuilder.cs is not used by your code, but the call `ProvisioningServiceClient.CreateFromConnectionString` creates a new ProvisioningServiceClient instance, which in turn calls `ServiceConnectionStringBuilder.Parse()`.
For more see [ProvisioningServiceClient.cs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/blob/master/provisioning/service/src/ProvisioningServiceClient.cs) in lines 82, 113 and 123.

**SOLUTION:**

To solve this you have to provide a SharedAccessKeyName. You should also consider using the [IotHubConnectionStringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.devices.client.iothubconnectionstringbuilder?view=azure-dotnet) for this which already checks your properties whhile building the connection string.

The questioner pointed out the key name is the deviceId according to this blog post [here](https://funwithiot.wordpress.com/2017/11/11/argumenterror-the-connection-string-is-missing-the-property-sharedaccesskeyname/). Thus, the solution is to use `SharedAccessKeyname=xx` instead of `DeviceId=xx`.

Comment: This post solved it for me, the key name is the device ID: https://funwithiot.wordpress.com/2017/11/11/argumenterror-the-connection-string-is-missing-the-property-sharedaccesskeyname/

Comment: @EvandroPomatti great. I'll edit your link into my answer, as I didn't find anything for the key name itself.

Comment: And perhaps this could also be of help, I got this directly from the portal, in the DPS access policies, within the Key 1 connection String: SharedAccessKeyName=provisioningserviceowner